# Whatever tickles their fancy in the US?

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, euphemisms

The delightful-sounding [tickle your fancy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tickle_someone%27s_fancy) is, I think, one of those rare idioms where the word order can be reversed and its meaning changes; the request: *fancy a tickle?* said with a raised eyebrow and a coy smile can  suggest light sexual foreplay, the addressee could be [tickled pink](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tickled+pink) at the idea and accept the offer.  Things get more serious between two people who have [taken a fancy to](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-a-fancy-to-someone) each other, as more often than not, they are “up for a bit of ***slap and tickle***”; a euphemistic phrase meaning sexual intercourse.

But not all relationships work out in the end, the bright initial spark that lit a fire fizzles out, and when a couple split they become [footloose and fancy-free](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/footloose-and-fancy-free).

It is my understanding that many of the expressions emphasized above are peculiar to British English, and I was wondering if north American speakers  *say* these expressions to one another?

- People of a certain generation still  say [“Whatever tickles your fancy”](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/7/messages/1132.html), but I fear it is becoming dated. **Nowadays**,  what do north Americans say? Are there modern-day equivalents of:

  1. tickle your fancy
  2. tickled pink
  3. take a fancy to
  4. footloose and fancy-free

  I am especially interested in hearing American English/slang idioms or expressions. The  rude ones, I know. If you would like to include snippets of their etymology, I'd be very tickled.

Comment: Would "you turn me on" cross the 'innocence' line? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+turn+me+on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20turn%20me%20on%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 no that's fine, not too sure how "modern" it is though. But it's definitely less dated.

Comment: Just as a side note, that's close to the Italian '*solleticare la fantasia*'. Same sexual nuance.

Comment: "Tickle your fancy" used to be quite common in the US, but I'd have to say I've not heard it much in recent years (possibly because it's acquired an undeserved hint of immorality).  (I'm quite sure that Tom Smothers played word games with the phrase on their old TV show.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with OP that *whatever tickles your fancy* is getting a bit "dated". The new kid on the block (AmE and BrE) is...

[image]

> [***whatever floats your boat***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whatever+floats+your+boat) - *see **whatever turns you on***

Comment: I haven't heard "floats your boat" in years.  But I'm having trouble recalling recent usage of any such idiom.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I've heard it a *lot* in the past couple of decades, so being BrE the first thing I did when I queried NGrams was compare relative prevalence in the US/UK corpuses. If anything the figures suggest it's actually *more* common in AmE. There's no doubt in my mind that even if it did exist a long time ago, it's coming very much to the fore today.

Comment: Yeah, the work environment I've been in for the past 5 years has been less apt to encourage the sort of free-flowing discussion where the term might be used, I suppose.  So I'm maybe not getting a good reading on it.

Comment: +1 as I think any snowclone of *whatever Xs your Y* would be understood, but *whatever floats your boat* may be the most mainstream. If I tell a friend or co-worker *hey, whatever creams your coffee* or *hey, whatever tickles your Elmo* I'd probably be understood, but I would never use such zany imagery in writing or more formal communication.

Comment: @choster: Good point. *Whatever [verbs] your [noun]* is pretty much a "set format" that we can ring the changes on for the general sense of *That's not for me, but it doesn't bother me if you like it*. I think maybe Mari-Lou has misunderstood *Whatever tickles your fancy* though, since it's only peripherally related to *footloose and fancy-free* (said of "unattached" people who're in the market for sex/romance).

Comment: If you look at the history of my post, you'll find I did include its definition, I decided to delete that description because 1) it's already in the two links 2) I suggested that reversing the word  order (fancy a tickle) changed the meaning quite significantly.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: *Fancy a fumble?* ;)

Comment: I fancy an Ngram chart comparing "whatever floats your boat" with "Whatever tickles your  fancy" and the green tick is yours if you succumb to my demands :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou: <sigh> I was kinda hoping *you* might succumb to *my* demands! :) Note that (at least so far as *I'm* concerned) the two expressions aren't exactly equivalent. A market-stall trader might say to a browsing potential customer *Just let me know if you see anything that tickles your fancy* (anything you like, which might be quite "ordinary"). But unless it was a "kinky sex toys" stall, he probably wouldn't say *...if you see anything that floats your boat* (which tends to imply something only suitable for those with "exotic" tastes, not shared by the speaker).

Comment: Toh, a downvote! Whatever for?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Perhaps because I only addressed one specific colloquial usage involving *fancy*. Not everyone [takes a shine to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=takes+a+fancy+to%2Ctakes+a+shine+to&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctakes%20a%20fancy%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctakes%20a%20shine%20to%3B%2Cc0) my style (they don't all fancy me either! :)

Comment: What do young people say for no.4? *I'm single*, seems boring, *I'm getting back into dating?* OK for divorcees.  *I'm young, free and single?* Boh?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Mostly what I hear lately is gender-neutral *She/he's a **slag*** for those who are "playing the field". The *social* imperative to get "paired off" is far less today, what with contraception, equal rights, welfare states, and the well-publicized fact that *most* marriages don't in fact survive. There's still the *emotional* imperative - but people are less likely to bring that up, because it implies undesirable "neediness".

Comment: The need to be "paired off" with someone is hard-wired into our psyche. Despite the break-up of social conventions, and people less concerned with respectability i.e. marriage etc. we still crave a mate, which is why this "need" does or can lead to promiscuity. What does a person say after a separation or a divorce? Saying "I'm available" sounds so cheap, saying "I don't have anyone special in my life" reeks of self-pity. *Footloose and fancy free* is, at least, cheerful and optimistic.  :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Bear in mind *footloose and fancy free* doesn't always and only mean *not romantically involved* - it can also be used of situations where you're not tied to your job or other commitments. What often I hear on movies/TV these days is *I'm not in a relationship right now*, but I'm not sure I've ever heard that one in real life. There's also the rather twee *I haven't met Mr Right yet* (and I've certainly never heard a *guy* say *I haven't met **Miss** Right yet* :)

Answer (score 1):

Today I happen to use the the phrase that you had brought up and coincidentally after reading several other websites and a brisk Google search along with definition...I had concluded,  I must be one of those Americans that still uses it here and there... "does that tickle your fancy or happy I was able to tickle your fancy".

I must be dated or I'm not caught up with modern times, but then again I sure still strive to have some humor in awkward conversations, which I mean, trying to make it less awkward for the both of us but still displaying I'm friendly with jokes. Especially now that this is 2022 conversations, compared to the 2015 original post, unfortunately conversations are mostly through your devices not face-to-face, where human contact is so scarce...so it's hard trying to figure out how awkward you made it with that phrase,  I know I had this evening, a good ole LOL always saves the day...

Have a good time out there making people show the inquisitive wrinkle on there face...

Age 34
Born and Raised American

Answer (score 0):

North Americans are not used to hearing these terms and we definitely do not use them often. The most common one, if I had to choose, is *taken a fancy to* (which is never used in a casual setting).

Here are some equivalencies I've run into:

- "Whatever tickles your fancy" = "Whatever suits you"
- "They've taken a fancy to each other" = "They're taking it to the next level" (kind of a silly one)
- "They're footloose and fancy-free" = "They're separated"

Of course since North America is such a big place, there are **tons** of different sayings that can be used here. More often than not, we'll use a saying that is more on the casual side — nothing too crazy or fancy.

Comment: Saying “whatever tickles your fancy” is perfectly fine cisatlantically. And your second one is merely annoying business jargon that should be given the dripping contempt it deserves.